# UIWebView display nothing but blank screen

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uitableview, xcode4.5

I created a `UITableViewCell` that contain `UIWebView` so I can display some bold texts for autocomplete

I tested the code with

```
-(void) setHTMLContent:(NSString *)HTMLContent
{
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<p><strong>bold</strong><br/><br/> <b>bold</b> </p>" baseURL:nil];
}
```

The `UIWebview` shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example in my app, and it outputs twice "bold" as expected, although in color black. So if your background is also black, you won't see anything. Maybe you simply set a different color?

Comment: I put UIWebView in UITableViewCell. Where do you put it?

Comment: I see, I just added it as a subview to my viewcontrollers view. How did you put it into the cell? As a background view?

Comment: using sophisticated technique actually. Perhaps that's where the problem is. Perhaps the UIWebView isn't even there.